# How to avoid Java dependency hell when using Maven multi-module projects

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I have been battling dependencies on a Java Maven multi-module project for a couple of days.

With too little oversight developers managed to create a situation where modules each can be compiled on their own but not as a single whole together. This results in all kinds of errors. Classes that cannot be found, casting errors etc etc. The cause of these problems seems impossible to determine.

My suspicion is that Maven puts conflicting dependencies on the class path. I think we made a mess of the Maven dependencies but regardless I don't understand how Maven can be such a poor performing framework for multi-module projects.

Now I can understand that Maven tries to do very smart useful things when compiling multiple modules as a whole but shouldn't there be an option in Maven to just configure a module to be isolated from other modules? Is there such an option? To avoid this dependency hell?

Or is the Maven best practice to create other scripts, bash scripts for example to be able to compile multiple modules in isolation, with one command?

But that is also poort workaround some tools for example SonarQube require  ability to run Maven on the whole code base in order to create a single project in SonarQube.

Comment: Maven can most definitely work very well with multi-module projects.  What it however cannot do is work with modules that have different (incompatible) versions of the same dependency (as you'd need multiple classloaders to get that to work).  Instead Maven will take the latest version of a dependency when there are multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

> This results in all kinds of errors. Classes that cannot be found, casting errors etc etc. The cause of these problems seems impossible to determine.

Could you post the error messages? it would make analyzing your issues easier.  This may be caused by dependency conflicts, but it is hard to say without more information.

> Now I can understand that Maven tries to do very smart useful things when compiling multiple modules as a whole but shouldn't there be an option in Maven to just configure a module to be isolated from other modules? Is there such an option? To avoid this dependency hell?

I do not get this.  If two modules do not depend on each other, their builds will be independent.  If one module depends on another module and its build fails because of version conflicts, this build will fail regardless of whether it is built together with the other modules or in isolation.

> Or is the Maven best practice to create other scripts, bash scripts for example to be able to compile multiple modules in isolation, with one command?

Maven follows the philosophy "convention over configuration", meaning the more you follow the convention, the less configuration you will have and the less maintenance work.  Creating all kinds of scripts goes against this philosophy and is not Maven's best practice.

To manage dependency conflicts in a multi module project, you would typically have a parent module with a pom.xml that looks like

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
                <version>6.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            ...
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <modules>
        ...
    </modules>
</project>
```

In the dependendencyManagement element you define the version of libraries used.  This way you force each module to use the same version of libraries.

For Maven, I often recommend the Java EE NetBeans IDE, because among other things it has a good visualisation tool for dependencies, which is useful in detecting and removing version conflicts.  (I am not aware of a similar tool in Eclipse or IntelliJ).  If you open a Maven project in NetBeans, click on the pom.xml (in the Projects window) and then select Graph > Show Graph.

I use this tool for 2 things:

1. remove the transitive dependencies in Maven, otherwise you have to manage more dependencies than required.  To remove transitive dependencies, right click in the graph and select the Hierarchical layout.  Every dependency that is not on the first line is a transitive dependency and can be removed from the pom.xml.
2. identifying conflicts between transitive dependencies.  (Conflicts are coloured red in the graph.)  I resolve these conflicts by explicitly setting the version for the dependencies in the dependencyManagement element in the root pom.xml

Comment: Eclipse has a similar view.  Double click the pom.xml, click on dependency hierarchy tab at the bottom.

Comment: "Dependency Hierarchy" shows output similar to mvn dependency:tree.  It is not as visual as the dependency graph in NetBeans.  Though it appears there also exist a "Dependency Graph" for Eclipse, I just do not have it installed and never looked how to install this for Eclipse.